# Using bit mask to automatch players in Android Development

Tags: android, criteria, multiplayer, bitmask

I am trying to automatch players based on their chosen criteria.  A player can be rated a level 1, 2 or 3 for simplicity.  If the player is a level 3 and only wants to play other level 3 opponents, how is this done?  I read page after page from Google's tutorials and references.  It states that the bitmask can be used to set criteria.  In my trials I was only able to match players when their bitmasks are the 2's complement of each other as stated in Google's documentation.

exclusiveBitMask - Exclusive bitmasks for the automatching request. The logical AND of each pairing of automatching requests must equal zero for auto-match. If there are no exclusivity requirements for the game, this value should just be set to 0.

So if two players have the same bitmask (i.e. the same criteria) they will NOT be matched.  What is the solution?  If they ARE matched based on 2's complement, how do I implement that?  Who gets the "regular" bitmask, and who get's the complement?  I don't understand.

I can give users the option to create a game:

my level ---- level willing to play against

1 1 0   ----  1 1 0  (zero meaning yes, so my level == 1 and willing to play level 1 only)

Along with an option to find a game:

level to play against ---- my level

0 0 1 ---- 0 0 1  (play against level 1, and I am level 1)

That is fine but then QuickGame is shot because either...

1)  two people on the same level won't get matched as in:

0 0 0 ---- 0 0 1 and 0 0 0 ---- 0 0 1  (NO MATCH, both level 1 and willing to play anyone)

2)  or if QuickGame is all zeros, they will match someone wanting to play ONLY level 3 as in:

0 0 0   ----  0 0 0  and 0 1 1 ---- 0 1 1 (QuickGame play anyone, and create game level 3 against level 3 ONLY is a match and that's not right)

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Give a chance `public RoomConfig.Builder setVariant (int variant)`
With `setVariant` you could create rooms for different player levels.

Comment: I have considered that.  Unfortunately that will not work.  A variant would only match another variant.  That would be good for Level 1 vs. Level 1.  However, I was looking to allow players to choose numerous level opponents to play.  User A:  Levels 1, 2 and 3  User B:  Levels 1 and 2.  User A should match User B but can not when using variants.  I am still looking for a way.  :(